# Удаление файла в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Как программно удалить файл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция `DeleteFile` удаляет файл, заданный именем `FileName`.

> `function DeleteFile ( const FileName : string ) : Boolean;`

Comment: Я пробовал его, почему-то не удаляет!

Comment: Всё, получилось!!! Спасибо!

Comment: Хорошо бы было написать все таки в чем была проблема и принять ответ если он вам помог, хотя для таких вопросов есть справочники ;)